# Setting up Apache directory root behavior

Tags: windows-xp, apache-http-server

I'm running Apache on a Windows machine for local testing and I'm new to it.

Currently, if I navigate to `localhost/` in a web browser, it will display an `index.html` page if one exists. Otherwise, it will display the directory listing.

- How can I make it so that navigating to a root directory will display more than `index.html`? What I need is so that if either: `index.html`, `index.htm`, or `index.php` exist, it will navigate to one of those.
- How can I disable showing directory roots? I would like it to return a 403 Forbidden error if no index page exists.

Answer (score 2):

First for the index part. Open up your httpd.conf file and look for this section.

```
#
# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
# is requested.
#
# The index.html.var file (a type-map) is used to deliver content-
# negotiated documents.  The MultiViews Option can be used for the
# same purpose, but it is much slower.
#        
DirectoryIndex index.htm index.html index.html.var
```

In most cases you won't add index.php here since it will either be in a separate conf or in the php.conf.

Then for your directory listing there are a few options. You can either use a .htaccess file or put it in the httpd conf. For the conf file you can add something like this.

```
<Directory /path/to/directory>
   Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```